# Is there any way to check whether an ordinal position contains a character or is empty?

Tags: string, python-2.7, unicode

If I print a character using its ordinal number with `unichr(orninal)` and the ordinal position does not contain any valid character, the result will be as:

```
>>> print unichr(0x0c80)
ಀ
```

Now I want to filter such null characters from a string and I tried `str.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')` as:

```
>>> print ''.join([unichr(i) for i in range(0x0c80, 0x0cff)]).encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
ಀಁಂಃ಄ಅಆಇಈಉಊಋಌ಍ಎಏಐ಑ಒಓಔಕಖಗಘಙಚಛಜಝಞಟಠಡಢಣತಥದಧನ಩ಪಫಬಭಮಯರಱಲಳ಴ವಶಷಸಹ಺಻಼ಽಾಿೀುೂೃೄ೅ೆೇೈ೉ೊೋೌ್೎೏೐೑೒೓೔ೕೖ೗೘೙೚೛೜ೝೞ೟ೠೡೢೣ೤೥೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯೰ೱೲೳ೴೵೶೷೸೹೺೻೼೽೾
```

But the null characters are still there. Is there any possible way to filter such characters?

Comment: The question you're asking is much more complex than you think. That's not a "null character". It's merely a character for which none of your installed fonts have a glyph available. The "character" as such is neither invalid nor "null", the code point may simply not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.category(unichr(0x08C0))
'Cn'
```

Cn is the category returned for a code point that has not been assigned to any character. (However, there's no guarantee it won't be assigned in a future version of Unicode.)

Comment: Also important: `>>> unicodedata.unidata_version`
`'x.y.z'`

Comment: `unicodedata.category(Unicode(0x08C0))`  is throwing this error: `NameError: name 'Unicode' is not defined`

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD use this instead `unicodedata.category(unicode(unichr(0x0c80)))`

Comment: sorry, should have just been `unichr`. Not sure if I mistyped or if SO's autocorrect caught me out...